# isSymmetric returns FALSE for symmetric matrix in R 3.2.2

Tags: r, matrix

I created a symmetric matrix that is required for input to the sem() function in R, but keep getting an error that says the matrix is not symmetric.

When I check element-by-element, I find no differences.

Does isSymmetric() check with a higher precision?  If so, how can I coerce the matrix to be symmetric in memory?

```
 SCA = c(1,.73,.70,.58,.46,.56)
 PPE = c(.73,1,.68,.61,.43,.52)
 PTE = c(.7,.68,1,.57,.4,.48)
 PFE = c(.58,.61,.57,1,.37,.41)
 EA = c(.46,.43,.4,.37,1,.72)
 CP = c(.56,.52,.48,.41,.71,1)

 ability = as.matrix(cbind(SCA,PPE,PTE,PFE,EA,CP))
 rownames(ability)=t(colnames(ability))

 ability.diag = diag(ability)
 ability[lower.tri(ability,diag=T)] = 0
 ability = ability + t(ability) + diag(ability.diag)
 ability
#      SCA  PPE  PTE  PFE   EA   CP
# SCA 1.00 0.73 0.70 0.58 0.46 0.56
# PPE 0.73 1.00 0.68 0.61 0.43 0.52
# PTE 0.70 0.68 1.00 0.57 0.40 0.48
# PFE 0.58 0.61 0.57 1.00 0.37 0.41
# EA  0.46 0.43 0.40 0.37 1.00 0.71
# CP  0.56 0.52 0.48 0.41 0.71 1.00
 sum(ability != t(ability))
# [1] 0
 isSymmetric(ability)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `isSymmetric` is implemented using the function `all.equal`. What is being tested is not whether the matrix is equal to its transpose, element by element, but whether these two matrices are equal as `R` objects. And in your case, they're not: if you look at their structure, you get the following:

```
> str(ability) 
num [1:6, 1:6] 1 0.73 0.7 0.58 0.46 0.56 0.73 1 0.68 0.61 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1, 1:6] "SCA" "PPE" "PTE" "PFE" ...
 ..$ : chr [1:6] "SCA" "PPE" "PTE" "PFE" ...


> str(t(ability))
num [1:6, 1:6] 1 0.73 0.7 0.58 0.46 0.56 0.73 1 0.68 0.61 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "SCA" "PPE" "PTE" "PFE" ...
  ..$ : chr [1, 1:6] "SCA" "PPE" "PTE" "PFE" ...
```

So the problem is with how the row names of `ability` have been generated. You can easily fix this:

```
> rownames(ability) <- colnames(ability)
> isSymmetric(ability)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or more simply: `isSymmetric(ability, check.attributes = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for pointing this out. However, if the function ```sem``` is indeed implemented using ```isSymmetric```, the OP needs to change the input (or rewrite the function using your comment).